# DocuSign API - RecipientView - How do you specify Excluded Documents?

Tags: docusignapi

From https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients I can see that when creating an Envelope Recipient, you can specify a list of documents within the DocuSign envelope that the Envelope Recipient cannot view.

I want to use similar functionality when creating a recipient view request (ie. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient#recipientViewRequest). Specifically, when creating a recipient view request I want to specify which documents the viewer can see/not see. However, I do not see an ExcludedDocuments parameter or similar.

How can I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RecipientView is simply the API method for obtaining an URL to a Signing Ceremony for a particular recipient.

If you don't want a recipient to see a document, then you must use Document Visibility--that includes using the `excludedDocuments` attribute, but other attributes and tabs need to be set up too.

Once you have an envelope with document visibility set up for some/all of the recipients, you can use RecipientView to obtain the URL for a specific recipient's signing ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Larry's response above is correct.

To set the document visibility for a specific recipient you could use this API endpoint:

PUT {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/{envelopeid}/recipients/{recipientid}/document_visibility

this is the information that you can set in the request body

```
{
  "documentVisibility": [
    {
      "recipientId": "sample string 1",
      "documentId": "sample string 2",
      "visible": "sample string 3",
      "rights": "sample string 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

so it could be something like this:

```
{
  "documentVisibility": [{
    "documentId": 1,
    "visible": false
  }]
}
```

I hope this helps!